# Logback-android: What's tagEncoder?

Tags: android, logback

I'm using logback-android(https://github.com/tony19/logback-android), and I'm trying to set some logback pattern.
then I refer to quick start in logback-android pages.

But I don't know what means about `<tagEncoder>`.

What's this? and What's difference between `<encoder>`?

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="logcat" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.android.LogcatAppender">
    <tagEncoder>
      <pattern>%logger{12}</pattern>
    </tagEncoder>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>[%-20thread] %msg</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="logcat" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we know, logs in android have TAG and Message structure
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

So tagEncoder would make TAG, and encoder would make Message in your log

You can use encoder without TAG, but it would be better to use TAGs too, for easy sort and search in logcat